# Unable to see split margin of GNU Screen

Tags: 14.04, gnu-screen

I installed screen in UBUNTU 14.04. The screen commands also runs successfully. But when I split screen horizontally, I am unable to see any split margin. Although split happens (able to switch using C-a). While splitting the screen vertically also, not able to see any vertical margin!!